# Missing term in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

This was asked in a reasoning test. I had to find the missing term $?$ in the following sequence -

$11, 18, 43, ? , 1201, y $

Problem is, I don't remember the question completely.

- ($y$ was some even number around $11000$ or $12000$ which I don't remember exactly).
- ($?$ had options in the range $100-200$)

It may seem that it lacks context or is incomplete but I would like to know if this can be solved with this much information, or if there is a familiar logical sequence anyone can think of for this?

Answer (score 2):

A nice formula is the sequence $(f(n))=(11,18,43,145,1201,11002)$, where
$$
f(x) = \frac{254 x^5}{5}-\frac{8735 x^4}{12}+3987 x^3-\frac{123445 x^2}{12}+\frac{61516 x}{5}-5315
$$

Comment: But I remember clearly that $y$ was even

Comment: Yes, $y=11002$ is even, done!

Comment: But you just found a 5 degree polynomial with f(1), f(2), f(3), f(5) values, and how could you come up with this in an exam?

Comment: @johndoe It has the values $f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6)$, and this is not a reasonable exam question, because it does not have an "obvious" answer related to the course for the exam.

Comment: You can find this using the following method: [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html)

Comment: I am voting for this problem be reopen. I think that it is interesting. Would you do the same ? Cheers.