# Find the missing number of the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question was asked to me in a reasoning test.
11, 18, 43, __, 1201, 11382

options are
a) 156
b) 184
c) 176

Please answer

Comment: The answers to these types of "logic riddles" are opinion-based and subjective. Therefore, these types of questions are off-topic on our site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing term in the sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461434/missing-term-in-the-sequence)

Comment: @TobyMak: you can make these problems well defined by specifying a set of allowed operations and their cost. You then ask a *minimum description length* solution. This one seems particularly challenging.

Comment: If that is the case, the OP should be the one that tells us what operations we can use. The OP hasn't shown us they have tried anything so far so I believe it is reasonable to downvote and close.

Comment: @TobyMak: I agree for the closing due to lack of effort, but the question is intriguing.

Comment: None of them.  It's 42.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a math question, seems like an IQ question of some sort.

You can put any value there and still be correct. Why? Because e.g. you can construct a polynomial $P(x)$ which returns these 6 values for $x=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: I always disagree with this "standard" answer. I believe that such quiz questions are in direct relation with Kolmogorov's complexity. For instance, there is a big difference between $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,\cdots$ and $1,2,4,8,16,31,64,128,\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

b) seems more appropriate as it is the only value that makes the curve of successive ratios convex. It also has the best correlation coefficient for the exponential of a quadratic polynomial. This is $100\%$ empirical and assumes that the values follow some smooth progression.